# How to create a character counter bot in api.ai?

Tags: slack, dialogflow-es

I'm an absolute knob when it comes to programming, so I ask of your help.

Essentially I'm trying to use the api.ai interface to create a character counter (in slack) where when a user says something like "hi" the bot will respond with "2".

So far I understand that I'm supposed to use an entity in order to achieve this transformation, and I have tried mapping reference words like "hi" with the synonym "2". However, the entity transformation ends up having the bot spew out exactly what the user initially said (ex. "hi"), instead of my desired outcome ("2").

Am I going about this wrong, or am I supposed to use an already existing entity to in my new entity? I apologize in advance as I literally picked this thing up yesterday, so I don't know much about it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write logic in api.ai, meaning you cannot write a function that takes as input a message and returns the number of characters.

What you would need, I believe, is to integrate the api.ai with an external web service where you can write your business logic.

Have a look at Slack + Webhook Integration Example https://docs.api.ai/docs/slack-webhook-integration-guideline

However, if you just want to count the number of chars in a message, I do not see the need for api.ai.